# How can I delete the first dot before the first number?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

How to remove the first dot before the first number?

For example

I have the following file

```
  more file


  Version …………2.465.76.8.332
```

I want to get only the version number - 2.465768.332

Comment: Your question title says _delete first dot_ but sample output shows something else.  Could you fix your question?

Comment: Also, what I never noticed, why do you remove the second and third dots from the version number? Is this a typo?

Comment: Can we get confirmation on this Q whether we actually want to delete the leading dots or both the leading dots plus the 2nd and 3rd dots as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming removing the dots from the version number is a typo.

`sed` can easily do the job:

```
echo 'Version …………2.465.76.8.332' | sed 's/^[^0-9]*//'
```

To extract only the version number from a file the number on is the first line beginning with 'Version' and nothing follows the version number, you could do:

```
sed -n '0,/^Version/ s/^Version[^0-9]*//p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` you could say:

```
sed -n '/Version/{s/^[^0-9]*//;s/\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)\./\1/p}' filename
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
2.46576.8.332
```

---

As mentioned in the comment, it isn't quite clear what is the desired output.  If it's the *expected output* as mentioned in the question body, you might use `awk` in order to improve readability:

```
sed -n '/Version/{s/^[^0-9]*//p}' inputfile | awk -F. '{print $1,$2$3$4,$5}' OFS=.
```

which would produce:

```
2.465768.332
```

Comment: This will also process the numbers from any other line in the file that happens to contain the string 'Version'

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP 'Version.*?\K[\d.]+$' filename
```